# Java - how can I read from .properties file with a use of maven profiles?

Tags: java, maven, properties

In pom file I have 2 profiles.
How can I read from urlOne.properties and urlTwo.properties with a use of mvn command:

mvn test -PurlOne (this command should run test with url: [www.pageOne.com](http://www.pageOne.com))

mvn test -PurlTwo (this command should run test with url: [www.pageTwo.com](http://www.pageTwo.com))

How can I pass correct properties filename to "InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME);" ?

Could you modify the code ? Thank you

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>urlOne</id>
        
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <env>local</env>
                            <properties.file>src/main/resources/urlOne.properties</properties.file>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>


    <profile>
        <id>urlTwo</id>


        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <env>local</env>
                            <properties.file>src/main/resources/urlTwo.properties</properties.file>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>

</profiles>
```

In src/main/resources I have 2 properties files: urlOne.properties and urlTwo.properties
Content of properties looks like this:

```
url=https://www.pageOne.com/

url=https://www.pageTwo.com/
```

In Hook class I have a method:

```
@Before()
public void before(Scenario scenario) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//User//Projects/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

   Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
properties.load(inputStreamReader);
    driver.get(properties.getProperty("url"));
```

How can I read from .properties file to open a test with correct url ?

Comment: Try `var propFile = System.getProperty("properties.file")`

Comment: Could you say more precisely ? Thank you

Comment: I have 2 profiles - both have the same "<properties.file>" - how can I choose correct .properties file with a use of "System.getProperty("properties.file")" ?

Comment: You can obtain all variables which defined in `systemPropertyVariables`  section using `System.getProperty([variableName])`. Then pass properties file path to `FileInputstream`'s constructor

Comment: Ok, but I have 2 identical "<properties.file>"

Comment: what will return this commnad: System.getProperty("properties.file") ? https://www.pageOne.com/ or https://www.pageTwo.com/ ?

Comment: In a different maven profile. And you put the correct maven command to activate a certain profile.

Comment: "What will return?" I think it's easier to try it out, than write more comments. No offense.

Comment: First properties for testing do not belong into `src/main/resources` better into `src/test/resources` ... furthermore why do you need a profile for that? Why not letting the integration test doing the handling of the different property files?

Comment: Solution with System.getProperty([variableName]) works - thank you very much